# using 'this' and ':not' together in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have this line of code `$(this).append("<b></b>")` and I want to add a :Not condition to it.

The best I could reach until now is `$(this:not('.someClassName')).append("<b></b>")` but of course it's not working.

What can I do?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
$(this).not(".someClassName").append("<b>");
```

You could also use a conditional:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("someClassName")) {
  ...
}
```

`:not` isn't really applicable to this situation unless you wanted to, for example, find all the descendants that don't have a particular class:

```
$(this).find(":not(.someClassName)")...
```

or

```
$(":not(.someClassName)", this)...
```

These two are equivalent.